# When I call Server API from iOS Using AFNetworking I got application/soap+xml error

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I have implemented following code and got the following error. I am unable to solve my problem :

```
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

> error:

```
{ status code: 500, headers {
"Cache-Control" = private;
"Content-Length" = 1666;
"Content-Type" = "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Fri, 12 Jun 2015 04:33:18 GMT";
Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.0";
"X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
"X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} }, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa4404463e0 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: application/soap+xml"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add application/soap+xml as an acceptable content type in your responseSerializer.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSet *acceptableContentTypes
```

e.g.

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/soap+xml", @"application/json", nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a more detailed answer [here](http://www.coderexception.com/C316mzN3PPXyyyyS/afnetworking-20-domainafnetworkingerrordomain-code1011-request-failed-internal-server-error-500).

I extracted this interesting part :

*The "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: application/soap+xml" error is generated by*

```
- (BOOL)validateResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response
                data:(NSData *)data
               error:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error
```

*method of AFHTTPResponseSerializer in case of unexpectable MIME type of response.*

*You can fix it with following code*

```
self.responseSerializer = [AFXMLParserResponseSerializer serializer];
NSSet *set = self.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes;
self.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [set setByAddingObject:@"application/soap+xml"];
```

*or modifying AFXMLDocumentResponseSerializer - add "application/soap+xml" to acceptable content types:*

```
- (instancetype)init {
self = [super init];
if (!self) {
    return nil;
}

self.acceptableContentTypes = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:@"application/xml", @"text/xml", @"application/soap+xml", nil];

return self;
```